# Как в ajax сделать чтоб css-класс срабатывал в двух местах одновременно?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Такая вот ситуация!Есть два одинаковых меню ajax-представления, одно находиться в хедере, второе в футере, при выборе пункта меню подчеркивается синей линией и переходит. Как сделать, что подчеркивало и в меню выбранный пункт и хедере и в футере?
Файл style.css:

```
.line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    }
```

Файл home.blade.php:

```
<!--Header-->
<ul class="dropdown-menu">    <!-- FIRST menu -->
    <li  class="loadBtn line"><a href="#top"> page 1</a></li>
    <li  class="loadBtn">     <a href="#top"> page 2</a></li>
    <li  class="loadBtn">     <a href="#top"> page 3</a></li>            
    <li  class="loadBtn">     <a href="#top"> page 4</a></li>
</ul>
<!--Content-->
<!--Footer -->
<ul class="dropdown-menu">    <!-- SECOND menu -->
    <li  class="loadBtn line"><a> page 1</a></li>
    <li  class="loadBtn">     <a> page 2</a></li>
    <li  class="loadBtn">     <a> page 3</a></li>            
    <li  class="loadBtn">     <a> page 4</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tpls = ['page1.blade.php', 
                'page2.blade.php',
                'page3.blade.php',
                'page3.blade.php'];

    $('.loadBtn').click(function(){

        $('.loadBtn').removeClass('line');
        $(this).addClass('line');

        loadContent($(this).index());
    });
    loadContent(0);

    function loadContent(index) {
        if (!tpls[index]) return;
        $.ajax({
            url: tpls[index],
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#content").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Может стоит попробовать плагины типа Scrollspy? Это если в меню якоря

Comment: ну переходить по якорю оно будет с помощью Scrollspy, так, а как применить класс line к двум меню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.loadBtn').click(function(){
                $('.loadBtn').removeClass('line');
                var index = $(this).index();
                var menus = $('.dropdown-menu');
                menus.each(function(i,el)
                {
                    var liArr = $(el).find('.loadBtn');
                    liArr.eq(index).addClass('line');
                });
                loadContent(index);
            });
```

пример: https://jsfiddle.net/mccn4zaz/

Comment: Изменил функцию click, как показано у Вас, результат:
перестало подчеркиваться в футере, даже если выбирается в футере

Comment: Пример : https://jsfiddle.net/mccn4zaz/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Alexboo/t204mohk/
вот.....сделал по Вашему.....в моем коде чего-то не работает.....наверное что-то мешает, а ЧТО не пойму...

Comment: У вас в примере не подключен Jquery.
var menus = $('.dropdown-menu');
на этой строке выбираются все меню, у вас у второго меню нету этого класса, поэтому на нем и не работает, либо добавьте ко второму меню этот класс либо измените селектор на 
var menus = $('.dropdown-menu, .navbar-nav');
[ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/w5ekoLa3/1/)

Comment: Hatsu, спасибо огромное, я уже разобрался, благодаря Вашему коду, я там добавил просто еще один класс, который и поместил в var menus, чтоб не мешать классам  bootstrap